# accessing created objects from other methods in c#

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I am writing a c# SSH tunneling program to consolidate dynamic tunneling into a single program, instead of using putty+firefox socks4/chrome socks4 plugin, typing in the same user/pass..ect. It is using the Renci.SSHNet library.

My question is this: When I create a new SshClient object, I want to be able to kill that connection later from a kill connection button, and also be able to run a separate thread that says while(isConnected) if (!addedToList) addtolist..The issue is that I am unsure of how to access different simultaneous running sshClient objects. Say I have 3 open connections to different hosts. If I select the host ip from current connections, I need a way to connect that ip address with the SshCLient connections and then run sshClient.Disconnect(). I realize that you can use sshClient.ConnectionInfo.Host.ToString() and match a string to that, but again if I am in a different method (kill connection button clicked) I don't know how to match host ip of 192.168.1.1 to an sshClient that is connected to that host.

I looked into weak references, but that seems to only work if I had only one sshClient. If there was a way to access currently created SshClient objects, then match it to the Host ip property, it would work. I can't find this in the Google.

I thought about scheming some elaborate way to create private object variable SshClients that are named after deviceIpString, but was unsure of how to create a variable that is named after another variable's contents (String).
such as:

```
deviceIpString = 192.168.1.1;
(i am pretending that backticks access the variable's data, since I dont know how to do it)
private SshClient 'deviceIpString' = new (SshClient(arguments));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The way that SO works is that answers should be posted as *answers*. Not as an edit to your question. Also, the way that we know that your question has been dealt with (to your satisfaction) is for you to *accept* an answer (not by editing your title and putting "resolved" or "answered" there). I'd recommend you visit the help centre or take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more familiar with SO.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I fixed the problem with a neat solution I have used in another program I wrote. I changed the name of question because this can be applied to any object of any type, as long as you can make an array of them. (not sure of a situation of where you can't, maybe a program only permits one object of that type)

The Solution: Create an private array to store all of the objects you want to reference later. Set it to a number of objects that you think is plausible to be created in the program. Then, create a private int variable for the index, starting at 0. Create a private void (or public if needed) method that accepts the object as an argument. The result should look like this:

```
private SshClient[] sshClients = new SshClient[10];
private int sshClientIndex = 0;
private void registerSshClient(SshClient sshClient)
{
  sshClients[sshClientIndex] = sshClient;
  ++sshClientIndex;
}
```

Then, when you get to the point where you are creating the object, add it into the array when necessary, using the register method. I do this after I verify the sshClient is connected. Then, come time when you need to do something with a specific object that you registered, find some type of data you can use to match it. My program adds the host ip to a listbox once the sshClient connects. I use this ip address to match the sshClient's connection info property. To match a certain object in the array, use a for loop. Here is my Kill Connection button for an example:

```
private void button_kill_connection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Object selectedConnection = null;
        selectedConnection = lbox_current_connections.SelectedItem;
        String selectedConnectionString = selectedConnection.ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i <= --sshClientIndex; i++)
        {

            if (sshClients[i].ConnectionInfo.Host == selectedConnectionString)
            {
                sshClients[i].Disconnect();
                lbox_current_connections.Items.Remove(selectedConnection);
            }
        }
    }
```

The for loop starts at the first array element (0) and progresses up until it reaches the amount of connections (objects actually stored) registered.